# Python datetime providing wrong timezone

Tags: python, datetime, sublimetext3

I have a plugin for SublimeText 3 that provides me with a timestamp for new documents. Everything works but I am getting the wrong timezone. I am Eastern Time but it is providing me with time 6 hours ahead (UTC).

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin
from datetime import datetime

class TimestampCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
  def run(self, edit):
    stamp = datetime.utcnow().strftime("%A %B %d, %Y | %H:%M:%S")
    for r in self.view.sel():
      if r.empty():
        self.view.insert (edit, r.a, stamp)
      else:
        self.view.replace(edit, r,   stamp)
```

Comment: You're clearly asking for `UTC` timezone here: `datetime.utcnow()`. Either you use `datetime.now()` or you will need to provide an offset to `datetime.utcnow()` to account for your timezone.

Comment: Thank you. I thought I read `utcnow` had to be used and I needed to provide an offset, but if I can just remove `utc` and use `datetime.now`, then I will go that route! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try `stamp = datetime.now().strftime("%A %B %d, %Y | %H:%M:%S")`

**datetime.now()** provides your local time.